# UWP - Make a keyboard shortcut call a function without using controls?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have this multi-line textbox that the user can type into. When they press "Ctrl + 1" it should insert a specific character like this sun symbol ☼ in the text box. I searched online and in the [Microsoft keyboard accelerators documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-accelerators), I found examples like these where a keyboard shortcut triggers a button to be pressed. But in my situation, I don't want buttons.

```
  <AppBarButton 
    Icon="Share" 
    Label="Share" 
    Click="OnShare" 
    AccessKey="S" />
  <AppBarButton 
    Icon="Copy" 
    Label="Copy" 
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Copy (Ctrl+C)" 
    Click="OnCopy" 
    AccessKey="C">
    <AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
      <KeyboardAccelerator 
        Modifiers="Control" 
        Key="C" />
    </AppBarButton.KeyboardAccelerators>
  </AppBarButton>
```

Comment: Sounds like it should be a event handler on the textbox - propably key press - that watches for this specific key combination of key and modifier.

Comment: WPF/UWP are designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other approaches, that misses about 90% of the pwoer and runs into problems quickly. The lack of Commands indicates that this might not be MVVM. With MVVM this whole operation *might* belong into the ViewModel wich would have to expose a proper Command for it. It is hard to tell without knowing what that Character does. I wrote a intro into MVVM a few years back, still seems to be valid a starting point: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register shortcut events on the page (such as MainPage).

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.Dispatcher.AcceleratorKeyActivated += AccelertorKeyActivedHandle;
}

private async void AccelertorKeyActivedHandle(CoreDispatcher sender, AcceleratorKeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.EventType.ToString().Contains("Down"))
    {
        var ctrl = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control);
        if (ctrl.HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down))
        {
            if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number1)
            {
                // add the content in textbox
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This registration method is global registration, you can run related functions when the trigger condition is met.

Best regards.

Comment: If I need another shortcut like "Ctrl + 2", can I add it in the current AccelertorKeyActivedHandle or do I have to create a separate "AccelertorKeyActivedHandle2"

Comment: By the way, thank you for this code. I don't know how you figured it out but I didn't find anything like this online.

Comment: If you need to add another shortcut, assuming Ctrl plus another button, you can append `else if(args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.[OtherKey])`

Comment: This is really awesome. You're a wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a function in your code which is triggered when a specific set of keys are pressed together.
For example, if you want to print an  emoji when the user presses "Ctrl + 1",
 write a function or a piece of code which is triggered when Ctrl and 1 are pressed 
 together and appends the text in the  multiline-textbox with the  emoji at the cursor 
 position.
I hope this will help.